# Global exception handling (non REST controller code)

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception, spring-annotations

I was trying to handle global exception but its not working without method call from REST API.

I have following code

```java
@SpringBootApplication 
public class LogReduceDemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(LogReduceDemoApplication.class, args);
        System.out.println(".......Started......");
        LogReduceDemoApplication.testException();
    }

    public static void testException() throws Exception {
        throw new Exception("testException...");
    }
}
```

Exception Handler

```java
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionHelper {

    static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ExceptionHelper.class.getName());

    @ExceptionHandler(value = { NullPointerException.class,Exception.class })
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleException(Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Inside handleException...");
        String msg="ex="+ex+", ex.getMessage()="+ex.getMessage();
        System.out.println("Exception Msg: "+ msg);
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(msg, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

When I am calling LogReduceDemoApplication.testException() method from REST controller then it is triggering exception handler. But when there is a call to the same method using main() function its not triggering Exception handler instead it is printing all exception details.

How to use exception handler for the method call from main function(not from REST controller)?

Comment: @ControllerAdvice methods only apply to controllers.

Comment: Yes...I am trying to find a way to handle exception globally for non controller code(example method call from main method or cron shedule etc)

Comment: Well you can use that handling, but then again - if its not in a REST-Context, it should not return a response object or anything like that. Instead it could be void and could contain some logic to handle and log the issues. 
Especially when handling request / response exceptions, which indeed return response objects you need to be vary cautios since manipulating the response object after returning the response (e.g. a already started file download from your rest-controller) itself leads to an exception and therefor has to be handled in another fashion

Comment: @phaen It should not in REST context....but everywhere I see REST based solution only...How to handle exception globally without REST context?

Comment: Its always in a "rest context" since its handled exceptions thrown within controllers / rest-controllers. That means its imo not a thing to handle "global npe". But rather have specific exceptions (e.g. by extending runtimeexceptions) which your controllers will throw and which are handled in the same way via those exception handler. It shall make it easier to treat exceptions the same way, but its not meant to be used on any exception thrown within your app. Its meant to be triggered on purpose handling specific exceptions in a specific way.

Answer (score 3):

You should try to use Aspects. Something like this:

```
@Component
@Aspect
public class LoggingAspect {    
       
    private final Logger logger =
            LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass().getSimpleName());               

    @Around("execution(* {YOU_PACKAGE_HERE}..*.*(..))")
    public Object someOperationAround(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
        Object result;
        try {
            long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            logger.debug("Calling {} with args: {} ",
                    pjp.getSignature().toShortString(),
                    pjp.getArgs());
            result = pjp.proceed();
            double duration = (System.currentTimeMillis() - t1) / 1000.;
            logger.debug("{} - Time elapsed: {}sec",
                    pjp.getSignature().toShortString(), duration);
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            logger.warn("When call {} with args: {} Exception thrown: {}",
                    pjp.getSignature().toShortString(),
                    pjp.getArgs(), ex.getMessage());
            throw ex;
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

Or @AfterThrowing instead of @Around if you need to catch only exceptions.

```
    @AfterThrowing(pointcut="execution(* {YOU_PACKAGE_HERE}..*.*(..)))", throwing="theExc")
    public void afterThrowingAdvice(JoinPoint theJoinPoint, Throwable theExc) {

        String method = theJoinPoint.getSignature().toShortString();
        System.out.println("\n=====>>> Executing @AfterThrowing on method: " + method);
    
        // log the exception
        System.out.println("\n=====>>> The exception is: " + theExc);    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't. It also does not make sense. The `@ExceptionHandler` method is returning a `ResponseEntity` that does not make sense outside the REST context.

Comment: How to do the same outside the REST context? I was searching the solution but everywhere I see REST based exception handling

Comment: `try {} catch() {}`?

Comment: I dont want to add try catch in all functions/files

Comment: But that's how it works in Java. The default exception handler for Spring controller is a specialty of Spring MVC. Otherwise use AOP (see the answer by @tuuka). This is what Spring is doing under hood as well.

Comment: I am trying with AOP but its printing default exception logs that I dont want....see this posted questions for the same https://stackoverflow.com/q/67635714/9024680

Comment: I am coming to this thread almost 2 years too late ... and I am a Spring newbie...

But I can describe the scenario (in my head) that brought me here.

Comment: But the scenario (in my head) that brought me here...

I want to throw a checked exception from an event listener from a bean that is specifically use to perform some one-time startup initialization. 

This will automatically wrap it in a UndeclaredThrowableException.

What I was looking for (similar to the OP) was a way to catch this UndeclaredThrowableException in some kind of global handler - unwrap it and then rethrow it to be caught by a more-specific exception-handler.